# Search and Delete a specific Item from a Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm doing a program that has a User Class with the following attributes:

```
private:
    char* username;
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
    ...
```

and in the main.cpp I have a vector of the class User:

```
#include <vector>
#include "User.h"

using std::vector;

void main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<User*> users;

    /*
        ... Some Code ...
    */
}
```

I have added some Users in the `/* ... Some Code ... */` place.

But now what I want from a program to do:

- Add a User

  - Search if user is added already (username in `users[i]` = username in new User)

    - do not add
    - `return false; // Confirm not added`
  - else

    - add user
    - `return true;  // Confirm added`

On the other hand I want to search for a user by username and delete it from the vector:

- Delete a User

  - Search if user is in the list (username in `users[i]` = username to be deleted)

    - delete user i
    - `return true;  // confirm deleted`
  - else

    - `return false; // confirm not deleted`

I hope you do understand what I mean.

Comment: that is really not "Search and Delete"

Comment: I understand, you want us to do your homework. By the way, there is no _Qt_ involved in your code...

Comment: A map might be better than a vector. And do you really want pointers in your container?

Comment: I'd agree with @awoodland: You probably want a `map` or a `set` for this task. Either handles your requirements much more directly than a `vector`. In fact, you're basically using a `vector` as a (rather inefficient) way to implement a `set`.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to search for how to Search for a class and do some functionalaties on it (e.g. add, delete) In C# List<> I can just do User[i].username but in C++ vector I cant do the same, I would have to first use Users.at(i) instead of Users[i] and I would not be able to select what exactly I want to check at

Comment: it is impossible to do Users.at(i).username [I dont know why

Comment: "*thank you for looking at my question*" -- I'm sorry, but I don't see a question anywhere. What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda

```
User newUser( name );
if ( std::find_if( user.begin(), users.end(), []( const User& u )->bool { strcmp( u.username, newUser.username ) == 0; } ) == users.end() )
{
    user.push_back( newUser );
}
```

(Thats off the top of my head so I may have made a mistake ...)

Comment: Can I Do the Delete in a same way?

Comment: user.pop_back( selectedUser );

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a pointer as the payload for an stl container.
It is not the recommended way.
Instead use a type that is copyable.
So you would have something like this - *vector<User> users;*

I think you should use *list* instead of *vector* because *vector* is not efficient when it comes to  deleting from the middle unless you have move semantics enabled.